# python break a function nested inside a loop

Tags: python, function, loops

I have the following piece of code:

```
for x in Listofurls:
    function(urlquery)
    function(htmlmining)
```

how the statement in function should be written
so that i can continue the loop moving to the next item 
when the query does not match my research like

```
def(urlquery):
    url=urlquery
    Urlopen = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    Url_read = parse(Urlopen)
    if 'text' not in Url_read.read():
        #here is where i want a statement to stop and go to the next
        #item in the loop  like 'continue' in a for loop
```

Comment: You can't control the `for` loop from inside `function` (also, what on earth is that syntax?) - you will need to `return` or `raise` something and deal with it outside `function`.

Comment: You wouldn't want the behaviour of the inner function to depend on whether it was called from a for loop or elsewhere.

Comment: sorry the the last lines were part of the same comment.

Comment: The code you've provided does not work at all, and is a mess, could you maybe fix it somewhat, and/or describe what it is you want to do a bit more carefully?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration) to exit from all loops until it's caught;

```
try:
  for i in range(10):
      if i == 5:
        raise StopIteration
      else:
        print i
except StopIteration:
  print "Caught"
```

gives:

0
1
2
3
4
Caught

The `StopIteration` `Exception` is exactly that, an exception, not an error;

> Raised by an iterator‘s next() method to signal that there are no
>   further values. This is derived from Exception rather than
>   StandardError, since this is not considered an error in its normal
>   application.

You can put it as deeply as you want in your nested loops, but you have to catch it at the level you want to break out of (i.e. the level at which you want to *stop iteration*) to.

Looking at your question, and trying to make sense of what you've written, it looks like you want to do something like this (maybe?)

```
for url in listOfURLs:
  if urlquery(url):
    htmlmining(url)


def urlquery(url):
  page = parse(urllib.request.urlopen(url))

  return 'text' in page.read():
    #here is where i want a statement to stop and go to the next
    #item in the loop  like 'continue' in a for loop
```

This will then only run `htmlmining(url)` when `'text'` is in the page you're parsing. If it's not, it will skip that entry and move onto the next one.

Comment: i am not sure this would work,i try to raise an Exception into the function nested in the loop not inside the loop but maybe this is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Have the inner function `return True` if you want to continue:

```
def urlquery(url):
    urlopen = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    url_read = parse(urlopen)
    if 'text' not in url_read.read():
        # here is where I want a statement to stop and go to the next
        return True
```

Then, the outer function can be:

```
for x in list_of_urls:
    if urlquery(x):
        continue
    htmlmining(x)
```

Note that the code you posted was not valid Python.  The above is my best guess as to what you meant.

Also, please read the [Python style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: thanks,this solution makes sense but it looks a little bit like a hack.

Comment: @addequttorr This how programming works.  If you want to control loop flow with the result of a function, the function must return something to tell the loop how to behave

Answer (score 0):

i finally found a solution to the question:

```
def urlquery(url):
    urlopen = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    url_read = parse(urlopen)
    if 'text' not in url_read.read():
        return
    else:
        myurl='text' in url_read.read()
        return myurl
```

and the for loop as follows:

```
for x in Listofurls:
    TextAvailable=function(urlquery)
    if not TextAvailable:
           continue
    function(htmlmining)
```

i am not sure this is the cleanest way to proceed but it works.